# Ruby on Rails Social Network- user_id produces error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

I am building a social network in Ruby on rails. I am trying to add user_id to a users status but it produces an error. The code can be found at my github: https://github.com/lewisfrost/treebook.git

Can you please help? I have been stuck on this all day!!

Thanks

Comment: NoMethodError in Statuses#index

Showing /Users/lewisfrost/treebook/app/views/statuses/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass<%= status.user.first_name %> <%= status.user.last_name %>

Comment: have you created the fk `user_id` on the status table?

Comment: @PinnyM is it not clearer to look at it on my github?  https://github.com/lewisfrost/treebook.git

Comment: @MrYoshiji what is the 'fk'? sorry for being a noob

Comment: Your `status` object has no `user` object associated with it. It means the fk (foreign key) `user_id` on the status object is null.

Comment: @MrYoshiji So how do I associate it with a user?

Comment: You can assign a user like this:  `user = User.find(expected_user_id); status = Status.find(4); status.user = user; status.save!`. Naturally this assumes you know which user is supposed to be assigned.  If you don't and you need one, then delete the status.  Otherwise leave as is and fix the view code.

Comment: by setting the user_id attribute of your status instancied object. I saw your project on github, you have an input for the user_id in the create view of a Status. But I advise you to read tutorials about Ruby on Rails before continue your project...

Comment: @MrYoshiji I am following a project on teamtreehouse.com. I copied everything the instructor did and it didn't work! So I deleted the project, started again and rewrote everything but it still doesn't work!

Comment: @LewisFrost, there's nothing necessarily wrong with the code except for some missing validation.  The error is because of a data issue which won't be corrected unless you manually fix it or drop and recreate the database from scratch.

Comment: @PinnyM Oh! Could you give me an idea of what i'd need to fix in the database? Thanks for your help

Comment: You can either assign a random user as I wrote above, or you can drop and recreate the database using `bundle exec rake db:reset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to try to get the first_name and last_name of your user associated with your status, you can use the very handy & meaning [method try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) !

You could do something like this in your view:

```
<strong><%= status.user.try(:first_name) %> <%= status.user.try(:last_name) %></strong>
```

It will try to get the first_name of the user if it exists, and not raise an error if the user doesn't exist!

Comment: Just got this error: NameError in Statuses#show

Showing /Users/lewisfrost/treebook/app/views/statuses/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined local variable or method `status' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc19b7d748>:0x007fbc1a1afd28>
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <p>
4:   <b>Name:</b>
5:   <%= status.user.try(:first_name) %> <%= status.user.try(:last_name) %>

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your `status` objects doesn't have an associated `user`.  Which in turn means that you can't display the `first_name` attribute.  You can find which status ids have this issue by running this in console:

```
puts Status.where(user_id: nil).map(&:id).inspect
```

If you want to ensure that a status actually *has* a user, you should:

- validate that a user is associated using: `validates :user_id, :presence => true`
- set your `:user_id` column to NOT NULL in the database:

  `change_table(:status){|t| t.references :user, :null => false }`

If you don't care if a user is assigned, then modify your view to only run that erb snippet if the :user_id is present.

Comment: that's what i got: 
1.9.3p194 :001 > puts Status.where(user_id: nil).map(&:id).inspect
  Status Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."user_id" IS NULL
[4]
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :002 >

Comment: So your status object with id '4' is the culprit...  If the `user` association is supposed to be mandatory, then either assign a user or delete it.